# How to convert an editbox to a number assembly?

Tags: winapi, assembly, x86, tasm

In TASM for Win32, I have this code:

```
;------- Edit1 Create ----------------
push    L 0
push    [hInstEdit1]
push    idEdit1
push    [newhwnd]
push    L 20
push    L 200
push    L 50
push    L 130
push    L WS_CHILD+WS_VISIBLE+WS_BORDER+ES_LEFT+ES_NOHIDESEL+ES_AUTOHSCROLL
push    L 0
push    offset EClassName
push    L 0
call    CreateWindowEx
mov [hEdit1],EAX

push    L SW_SHOW
push    [hEdit1]
call    ShowWindow
push    [hEdit1]
call    UpdateWindow
```

I need to get the number entered by the user in this editbox.
The number must be placed in the register.
Who knows how to do this?

PS I think you need to use the function GetDlgItemInt

Comment: You need the asm equivalent of `BOOL success; UINT number = GetDlgItemInt(newhwnd, idEdit1, &success, signed);` where `signed` is true or false depending on whether you want a signed or unsigned number. Also, consider adding the `ES_NUMBER` style to your Edit control

Comment: Since you already have the handle of the edit window there should be no need to call GetDlgItem. GetDlgItem is for cases where you don't have the HWND and need it (such as in a dialog procedure where you have the HWND of the dialog but not those of the child controls).

Comment: @SoronelHaetir read the documentation for `GetDlgItemInt()`, it takes the parent window and child ID as input. If you want to use the Edit control directly, you will have to use `WM_GETTEXT` or `GetWindowText()` and parse the text manually.

Comment: Sigh, I am blind and did not hear the "Int".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the way found on the Internet

```
                            ; Input:
    mov esi, offset szMsg1  ; esi - str
    dec msgLength           
    mov ecx, msgLength      ; ecx - length str
                            ; Output:
                            ; EAX = integer value
string_to_int:
    xor ebx,ebx             ; clear ebx
next_digit:
    movzx eax, byte ptr [esi]
    inc esi
    sub al,'0'              ; convert from ASCII to number
    imul ebx,10
    add ebx,eax             ; ebx = ebx*10 + eax
    loop next_digit         ; while (--ecx)
    mov eax,ebx
```

Comment: Decrementing the message length before loading it instead of `dec ecx` looks like a bug.  Also, you don't handle the case of length being zero.  And if you want the total in EAX at the end, accumulate it there: `movzx` into EDX or something and do `eax = eax * 10 + digit`.  (You don't need to touch EBX, which is call-preserved so you have to save/restore it if you use it.)